# Calling a method in the main

Tags: java, methods, call, identifier

```
public class CalculatePi {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double pi = 0.0;
        System.out.println("Iteration Pi");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%4d %14.12f\n", i , pi);
        }
    }

    public static double calcPi(int count) 
    {
        double pi1 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            pi1 += Math.pow(-1,i)/(2*i+1);
        }
        double actpi = pi1 * 4;
        return actpi;
    }
}
```

I need to call the calcPi method in the main but everyway I have tried I have been unable to do so. I want to make the table created by the main show the values of actpi found in the calcPi.

Comment: What language is this? Java?

Comment: Yes this is Java, can you tell me the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

You can call it with by referencing it by name and pass `i` in the parenthesis:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Iteration Pi");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%4d %14.12f\n", i , calcPi(i));
        // Here -------------------------------^
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you for such a fast response that was so simple :P

Comment: @S.Pirate If this is the correct answer, then mark it as the correct answer.